# Why is my page displaying small A+Japanese character icons?

Tags: browser-compatibility

I have a Wordpress page that, upon load, displays a couple small icons in the left margin. When I left-click on them, they disappear. When I right-click, they appear to be a local Mozilla image under a  moz-extension://<hash>/icons/512.png Does anyone know what these are and how to make them go away? The icons do not appear in Chrome or Edge.

I am a Wordpress novice, so please bear with me.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it comes from some browser extension?

Comment: I think those are translate icons, coming from either Google or other browser plugin, as [anton said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388277/why-is-my-page-displaying-small-ajapanese-character-icons#comment563378_388277). Is there a space or nbsp on that position? It might be that your browser (or plugin) is trying to translate that text.

Comment: @josfaber, anton - Thanks for the information. I will check tonight.

Comment: @anton Yep, It was from a translation browser extension for Firefox on that particular machine. It only appears in Firefox obviously, and only follows that extension. Thanks for you insights.

Comment: You are welcome. I will add my comment as an answer, let's remove this question from unanswered list if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a path you provided `moz-extension://<hash>/icons/512.png`, this icon comes from Firefox translation extension.